# Is there any easer way to wipe all fixed sizes set for html nodes than I trying to code?

Tags: c#, html, .net, string, replace

I have an input strings like that:

```
<span id = 'RTF_Text_101'  style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:12pt;text-align:left;">
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">aeqw</span></p>
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">qwe</span></p>
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">qwe</span></p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0pt" style="width:498.2pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
<colgroup>
<col width="332" />
<col width="332" />
</colgroup>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
<td style="width:244pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">asd1</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:244pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">asd3</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="left" valign="top">
<td style="width:244pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">asd2</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width:244pt; padding-right:1.8pt; padding-left:1.8pt; border-top: 1pt solid #000000; border-right: 1pt solid #000000; border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000; border-left: 1pt solid #000000;">
<p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size:10pt;">asd4</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</span>
```

Those are generated by rtf to html conversion tool. The problem is that it makes tables with fixed sizes, while I need it to be dynamic.

So, I need to replace all sizes (width, height) in this string that belongs to table related tags (table, tr, td).

I started to code this:

```
//the input parameters for this funct is huge html piece and tag that should be "non sized"
public void RemoveSizesFromStringForTag(ref string str, string tag)
{
    int tag_start_index = -1; //current found tag start index
    int curr_search_pos = 0; //current position to start search for next tag

    while ((tag_start_index = str.IndexOf("<" + tag, curr_search_pos)) >= 0) //while we found some tag
    {
        int tag_end_index = str.IndexOf(">", tag_start_index); //get it's end index
        string temp_part = str.Substring(tag_start_index, tag_end_index - tag_start_index); //substring tag liek that "<table ... >"

        bool replace_needed = false; //used as flag

        if (temp_part.ToLower().Contains("width")) //if substring contains width
        {
            //NOT IMPLEMENTED
            RemoveAttributeFromString(ref temp_part, "width"); // then remove this attribute from that string
            replace_needed = true; //and mark that we need to replace later
        }

        if (temp_part.ToLower().Contains("height"))
        {
            RemoveAttributeFromString(ref temp_part, "height");
            replace_needed = true;
        }

        if (replace_needed) // if replace needed
        {
            str.Remove(tag_start_index, tag_end_index - tag_start_index); //we remove string with sizes
            str.Insert(tag_start_index, temp_part); //and insert string without sizes
        }

        curr_search_pos = tag_start_index + temp_part.Length; //correcting current search position
    }
}

public void RemoveAttributeFromString(ref string str, string attr)
{
    int attr_start_index = -1;
    int curr_search_pos = 0;

    while ((attr_start_index = str.IndexOf(attr, curr_search_pos)) >= 0)
    {
        //honestly I stopped here to understand what to do next,
        //since stoo much of cases possible that I cannot handle.

        //it could be: id = 'asd'width='10%'height=5px, it could be with spaces, with ", set via style width:10%
    }
}
```

And at certain point I found that my approach is very hard, because that sizes could be set by many ways `(width=10px, width = 10px, width = '10px', id='asd'width="10px"style='...')`. There is too many cases and it very hard to find the attribute borders to remove.

So, is there any easer aproach?

Comment: if you have a complete html document rather use HtmlAgilityPack... to be had via nuget. more safe and easier to use too

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger - sorry, I don't know what you talking about. I have only certain html portions that starts from `<span>`

Comment: all widths and heights should be set to the same values?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger - they should be removed, like were never set. For table related tags only (table, tr, td)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be read as well formed xml (at least the example you posted):

**Edit**

A lot easier to read:

```
private static string RemoveHeightsAndWidths(string original)
{
    XElement element = XElement.Parse(original);
    var tableRelatedElements =
        element.Descendants("table")
        .Union(element.Descendants("tr"))
        .Union(element.Descendants("td"))
        .Union(element.Descendants("th")); //add more items you want to strip the height and width from in the same manner

    Regex reg = new Regex("(?:width:.*?;)|(?:height:.*?;)");

    foreach (var item in tableRelatedElements)
    {
        if (item.Attributes("style").Any())
        {
            item.Attribute("style").Value = reg.Replace(item.Attribute("style").Value, string.Empty);
        }
        if (item.Attributes("height").Any())
        {
            item.Attribute("height").Remove();
        }
        if (item.Attributes("width").Any())
        {
            item.Attribute("width").Remove();
        }
    }

    return element.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting solution. I will test it how it working. Actually, sizes could be also set through tag attributes (width = 10px)

Comment: You would also need to remove the attributes from the `col` tags

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing onto it, however this is easer. I will simply remove whole `<colgroup>`.

Comment: Looks like it hasn't wiped such values from table tag: `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0pt" style="width:498.2pt;` and... those probably also can be with `,`

Comment: Oh... I just noticed, do it wipe sizes for other tags like `img`? This should not happen. Only for table, tr and td. But anyway it's great answer already. Way shorter and easer that I coded.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all this help. I kinda don't know Linq, but will resolve the remain checks. Have a good day!

Comment: Now is a good time as any to learn then... makes life A LOT easier as you can see =)

Comment: Right, if say honestly I don't understand what half of your code does :O Gotta learn something.

Comment: @Kosmos Updated the method so you can better read what's going on. Now it only strips the table/td/tr/th s too...

Comment: Right, now it more clear for understanding. Thank you, you are great!